# SDSS taget data missing

Tags: data-pipeline

I am student who want to do project with SDSS DR7 photometric data. (My target is NGC2420.)
I extract ugriz magnitude data by SQL, but it was 'punched'. Target data was missing.
I don't have any ideas How can i get those data from SDSS SQL?

[image]

SDSS Skyserver anounces to me they have data about Target
but SQL data is punched.

[image]